# YAML - Dumping a nested object without types/tags

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to dump some Python objects out into YAML.

Currently, regardless of YAML library (`pyyaml`, `oyaml`, or `ruamel`) I'm having an issue where calling `.dump(MyObject)` gives me correct YAML, but seems to add a lot of metadata about the Python objects that I don't want, in a form that looks like:

`!!python/object:MyObject` and other similar strings.

I do not need to be able to rebuild the objects from the YAML, so I am fine for this metadata to be removed completely

Other questions on SO indicate that the common solution to this is to use `safe_dump` instead of `dump`.

However, `safe_dump` does not seem to work for nested objects (or objects at all), as it throws this error:

```
yaml.representer.RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', MyObject)
```

I see that the common workaround here is to manually specify Representers for the objects that I am trying to dump. My issue here is that my Objects are generated code that I don't have control over. I will also be dumping a variety of different objects.

Bottom line: Is there a way to dump nested objects using `.dump`, but where the metadata isn't added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the words "correct YAML" are not really accurate, and would be better phrased as
"YAML output looking like you want it, except for the tag information", this fortunately gives some
information on how you want your YAML to look, as there are an infinite number of ways to dump objects.

If you dump an object using `ruamel.yaml`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

class MyObject:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      self.c = [a, b]

data = dict(x=MyObject(42, -1))


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='unsafe')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this gives:

```
x: !!python/object:__main__.MyObject
  a: 42
  b: -1
  c: [42, -1]
```

You have a tag `!!python/object:__main__.MyObject` (yours might differ depending on where the
class is defined, etc.) and each of the attributes of the class are dumped as keys of a mapping.

There are multiple ways on how to get rid of the tag in that dump:

#### Registering classes

Add a `classmethod` named `to_yaml()`, to each of your classes and
register those classes. You have to do this for each of your classes,
but doing so allows you to use the safe-dumper.  An example on how to
do this can be found in the
[documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html)

#### Post-process

It is fairly easy to postprocess the output and remove the tags, which for objects always occur on the line
before the mapping, and you can delete from `!!python` until the end-of-line

```
def strip_python_tags(s):
    result = []
    for line in s.splitlines():
        idx = line.find("!!python/")
        if idx > -1:
            line = line[:idx]
        result.append(line)
    return '\n'.join(result)

yaml.encoding = None
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=strip_python_tags)
```

and that gives:

```
x: 
  a: 42
  b: -1
  c: [42, -1]
```

As achors are dumped before the tag, this "stripping from `!!python`
until end-of-the line", also works when you dump object that have
multiple references.

#### Change the dumper

You can also change the unsafe dumper routine for mappings to
recognise the tag used for objects and change the tag to the "normal"
one for dict/mapping (for which normally a tag is not output )

```
yaml.representer.org_represent_mapping = yaml.representer.represent_mapping

def my_represent_mapping(tag, mapping, flow_style=None):
    if tag.startswith("tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object"):
        tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map'
    return yaml.representer.org_represent_mapping(tag, mapping, flow_style=flow_style)

yaml.representer.represent_mapping = my_represent_mapping

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

and that gives once more:

```
x:
  a: 42
  b: -1
  c: [42, -1]
```

These last two methods work for all instances of all Python classes that you define without extra work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed walkthrough, and examples for each of the options. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Just out of curiosity: which solution are you going to use?

Comment: It writes as `dictitems: {a: 4}
state: {filename: test.yaml}` would it be possible to ignore writing `dictitems ` and `state `

Comment: @alper Please post a question and tag it ruamel.yaml, then you can properly describe what you now get (with formatting) and what you want to get. Make sure your wanted output is valid YAML because `{a: 4} {filename: test.yaml}` is not, not even when it is on two lines.

Comment: Your answer on that link also does not work which gives: `ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: {'a': 3}`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68678764/ruamel-yaml-representer-representererror-cannot-represent-an-object-value   . If I can make it work I believe I can combine it with your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and hacky:

`"\n".join([re.sub(r" ?!!python/.*$", "", l) for l in yaml.dump(obj).splitlines()]`

- `"\n".join(...)` – concat list to string agin
- `yaml.dump(obj).splitlines()` – create list of lines of yaml
- `re.sub(r" ?!!python/.*$", "", l)` – replace all yaml python tags with empty string