# How can I dump changes corresponding to list using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am using solution in the related answer for [How to auto-dump modified values in nested dictionaries using ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694688/2402577)
 with `RoundTripRepresenter`.

If I make chnages on a `list`, `ruamel.yaml` is able to make changes on the local variable, but it does not dump/write the changes into the file. Would it be possible to achive it?

Example config file:

```sh
live:
- name: Ethereum
  networks:
  - chainid: 1
    explorer: https://api.etherscan.io/api
```

For example I changed `name` into  `alper` and tried to append new item into the list.

my code:

```py
class YamlUpdate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config_file = Path.home() / "alper.yaml"
        self.network_config = Yaml(self.config_file)
        self.change_item()

    def change_item(self):
        for network in self.network_config["live"]:
            if network["name"] == "Ethereum":
                network["name"] = "alper"
                print(network)
                network.append("new_item")

yy = YamlUpdate()
print(yy.config_file.read_text())
```

output is where `name` remains unchanged on the original file:

```sh
{'name': 'alper', 'networks': [{'chainid': 1, 'explorer': 'https://api.etherscan.io/api'}]}
live:
- name: Ethereum
  networks:
  - chainid: 1
    explorer: https://api.etherscan.io/api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at making a class `SubConfigList` that behaves like a list but notifies its parent (in the datastructure), like in the other answer where `SubConfig` notifies its parent.

You'll also need to make sure to represent `SubConfigList` as a sequence into the YAML document.

If you ever going to have list at the root of your data structure, you'll need to have list-like alternative to the dict-like `Config`. (Or document for the consumers/users of your code that the root  always needs to be a mapping).

Comment: Would it be possible to make a hybrid class that can handle `list` and `dict`?

Comment: If I do your advice on your answer could `SubConfig` still used for `dict`?

Comment: Yes you can make a hybrid class, but IMO more difficult than necessary, I would not attempt it if I were you. I don't understand why you need to as about `Subconfig`, of course you still need that as intelligent `dict`, but you might need to make it `SubConfigList`  aware and vv.

Comment: I may have think more complex to solve this. I just wanted to inser an item in to a list using ruamel, actually it shouldn't be `dict-like`