# How can I keep comments of a yaml file when modify its values in nested dictionaries using ruamel.yaml

Tags: comments, ruamel.yaml

I'm using solution in the related answer for [How to auto-dump modified values in nested dictionaries using ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694688/2402577), which uses the default (round-trip) loader/dumper.

I believe, it is a hard problem since additinal `dict` should keep comments as well.

=> Would it be possible to prevent comments to be removed if we use `modify values in nested dictionaries using ruamel.yaml` approach?

---

**Example:**

config.yaml:

```
c:  # my comment
  b:  
   f: 5  
a:
  z: 4
  b: 4  # my comment
```

code (same code from [How to auto-dump modified values in nested dictionaries using ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694688/2402577)
), which changed to use the default `(round-trip) loader/dumper`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, representer


class SubConfig(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def updated(self):
        self.parent.updated()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            v = SubConfig(self)
            v.update(value)
            value = v
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.updated()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            res = super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            super().__setitem__(key, SubConfig(self))
            self.updated()
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        return res

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        res = super().__delitem__(key)
        self.updated()

    def update(self, *args, **kw):
        for arg in args:
            for k, v in arg.items():
                self[k] = v
        for k, v in kw.items():
            self[k] = v
        self.updated()
        return


_SR = representer.RoundTripRepresenter
_SR.add_representer(SubConfig, _SR.represent_dict)


class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, filename, auto_dump=True):
        self.filename = filename if hasattr(filename, "open") else Path(filename)
        self.auto_dump = auto_dump
        self.changed = False
        self.yaml = YAML()
        self.yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
        self.yaml.default_flow_style = False
        if self.filename.exists():
            with open(filename) as f:
                self.update(self.yaml.load(f) or {})

    def updated(self):
        if self.auto_dump:
            self.dump(force=True)
        else:
            self.changed = True

    def dump(self, force=False):
        if not self.changed and not force:
            return
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            self.yaml.dump(dict(self), f)
        self.changed = False

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            v = SubConfig(self)
            v.update(value)
            value = v
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.updated()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            res = super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            super().__setitem__(key, SubConfig(self))
            self.updated()
        return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        res = super().__delitem__(key)
        self.updated()

    def update(self, *args, **kw):
        for arg in args:
            for k, v in arg.items():
                self[k] = v
        for k, v in kw.items():
            self[k] = v
        self.updated()


cfg = Config(Path("config.yaml"))
```

=> `config.yaml` file is updated as follows, where its comments are removed:

```
c:
    b:
        f: 5
a:
    z: 4
    b: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to prevent comments from being lost. The object returned from `self.yaml.load()` in your `Config.__init__()` method is not a dict, but a subclass thereof (`ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap`) that includes all of the comment information (in its `.ca` attribute. And that `CommentedMap` will have values that are in itself again `CommentedMap` instances (at least with your input.

So what you need to do is change your classes:

```
class Config(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
```

and do the same for `SubConfig`. Then during the `update` routine you should try to copy the `.ca` attribute (it will be created empty on the `CommentedMap`, but not be available on `{}`)

Make sure you all add a the representer for `Config`, and **don't** cast to `dict` in your `Config.dump()` method.

---

If you also copy the `.fa` attribute of the loaded data (also on `Subconfig`), you'll preserve the flow/block style of the original, and you can do a away with the `self.yaml.default_flow_style = False`.

---

The above is the theory, in practise there are a few more issues.

Your `config.yaml` changes, although you do not explicitly dump. That is
because  your `auto_dump` is True by default. But that also means it
dumps for every change, i.e. your `config.yaml` gets dumped 10 (**ten**) times while the
`Config`/`SubConfig` data structure gets build.
I changed this to dump only once if `auto_dump` is `True`, but even that I would not
recommend, instead only dump if changed after loading.

A `dict` doesn't need initializing, but a `CommentedMap` does.
If you don't you get an attribute error at some point. So you'll have to
call `super().__init__(self)` in each the `__init__` of each class.

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

_SR = ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter

class SubConfig(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__(self)

    def updated(self):
        self.parent.updated()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            v = SubConfig(self)
            v.update(value)
            value = v
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.updated()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            res = super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            super().__setitem__(key, SubConfig(self))
            self.updated()
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        return res

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        res = super().__delitem__(key)
        self.updated()

    def update(self, *args, **kw):
        for arg in args:
            for k, v in arg.items():
                self[k] = v
            for attr in [ruamel.yaml.comments.Comment.attrib, ruamel.yaml.comments.Format.attrib]:
                if hasattr(arg, attr):
                    setattr(self, attr, getattr(arg, attr))
        for k, v in kw.items():
            self[k] = v
        self.updated()
        return


_SR.add_representer(SubConfig, _SR.represent_dict)


class Config(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
    def __init__(self, filename, auto_dump=True):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.filename = filename if hasattr(filename, "open") else Path(filename)
        self.auto_dump = False  # postpone setting during loading of config
        self.changed = False
        self.yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
        self.yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
        # self.yaml.default_flow_style = False
        if self.filename.exists():
            with open(filename) as f:
                self.update(self.yaml.load(f) or {})
        self.auto_dump = auto_dump
        if auto_dump:
            self.dump()

    def updated(self):
        if self.auto_dump:
            self.dump(force=True)
        else:
            self.changed = True

    def dump(self, force=False):
        if not self.changed and not force:
            return
        # use the capability of dump to take a Path. It will open the file 'wb' as
        # is appropriate for a YAML file, which is UTF-8
        self.yaml.dump(self, self.filename)
        self.changed = False

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            v = SubConfig(self)
            v.update(value)
            value = v
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.updated()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            res = super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            super().__setitem__(key, SubConfig(self))
            self.updated()
        return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        res = super().__delitem__(key)
        self.updated()

    def update(self, *args, **kw):
        for arg in args:
            for k, v in arg.items():
                self[k] = v
            for attr in [ruamel.yaml.comments.Comment.attrib, ruamel.yaml.comments.Format.attrib]:
                if hasattr(arg, attr):
                    setattr(self, attr, getattr(arg, attr))
        for k, v in kw.items():
            self[k] = v
        self.updated()

_SR.add_representer(Config, _SR.represent_dict)

fn = Path('config.yaml')
fn.write_text("""
c:  # my comment
  b:
     f: 5
  x: {g: 6}
a:
  z: 4
  b: 4  # my comment
""")
cfg = Config(fn)
print(Path(fn).read_text())
```

which gives:

```
c:  # my comment
    b:
        f: 5
    x: {g: 6}
a:
    z: 4
    b: 4 # my comment
```

Since the input changes, I write the config file to test out on every run.
I also added a flow style dict, to make clear that original formatting is performed.

Comment: After switching into `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap`, it gives error at `self._ok.add(key)` line where it gives error at: `ruamel/yaml/comments.py", line 936, in __setitem__   AttributeError: _ok`

Comment: That is because you don't initialize the `CommentedMap`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer that covers all

Comment: When `c:  # my comment` written as `    c:  # my comment` (having 4 space before ) , its comment also have 4 space instead of 2, is it a normal behavior?

Comment: The comments only "know" in what column they started and `ruamel.yaml` tries to put them back in that column, so normally you neatly aligned comments stay aligned, If that column is no longer available (because of re-indentation or longer YAML data on the line before it, the comment gets pushed back on the line. A comment doesn't have an idea of distance. But I don't guarantee that for comments between keys and their values, and what is done there might change in the future.